# Create image from data-in-uri (base64-encoded PNG) in ActionScript

Tags: html, flash, image, actionscript, base64

I have a string of of base64-encoded PNG image that is suitable to use as a src (source) attribute in a `<img>` tag. However I need to transfer this image to Flash applet where I need to create (show) the image **fast**. Is there a way to simply use the data string and somehow create an image (inside a Flash movie) from it?

**Performance of the operation is a core requirement.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least you must decode the base-64 data into binary. You can then load the binary data as an image using Loader.loadBytes().

Here's a fast base64 decoder compiled with alchemy: [http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/](http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto)

```
var bytes:ByteArray = by.blooddy.crypto.Base64.decode(string);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.loadBytes(bytes);
```

Update: You can use the "Textfield.getImageReference()" to gain access to the Loader for  tag. Once you have it you can tell it to load the image bytes, like this:

```
textfield.htmlText = 'hello <img id="myImage" src="" /> hello';
var image:DisplayObject = textfield.getImageReference("myImage");
var loader:Loader = image as Loader;
loader.loadBytes(bytes);
```

Here's a complete end-to-end example:

```
var textfield:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(textfield);
textfield.htmlText = 'hello <img id="myImage" src="" /> hello';

var data:String = "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";

var bytes:ByteArray = by.blooddy.crypto.Base64.decode(data);

var image:DisplayObject = textfield.getImageReference("myImage");

var loader:Loader = image as Loader;
loader.loadBytes(bytes);
```